# The open-jdk build number is changing and it is affecting JAVA path set in the Dockerfile

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

The open-jdk build number is changing and it is affecting JAVA path set  in the Dockerfile.

The build number changed from java-1.8.0-openjdk-**1.8.0.352.b08-2.**amzn2.0.1.x86_64 to java-1.8.0-openjdk-**1.8.0.362.b08-1**.amzn2.0.1.x86_64

below is the code

```
RUN yum update -y && 
    yum -y install yum-plugin-versionlock && \
    yum -y versionlock add java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.362.b08-0.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 && \
    yum -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk && \
    yum clean all
```

I tried adding a version lock, but it doesn't control the build number. I understand the RUN commad in docker starts a new shell and none of the variable persist. Two ways I tried to solve the problem

1. Capture path using JAVA_PATH=$(ls /usr/lib/jvm |grep java) and then use it for JAVA_HOME
2. Used a shell script to RUN the above the command
3. Which java may not work if it not backward compatible.

The solution should run in Dockerfile and consistently get the same openJDK build number. thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider using a Linux distro with reproducibility as a stronger design goal. NixOS in particular lets you get packages as they existed of a specific prior point in time. (It also provides [its own tooling for building Docker images](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#sec-pkgs-dockerTools), so one doesn't need to use Dockerfiles at all in the first place... though with Nix's much stronger isolation features, one doesn't have as much need for containerization as a whole either).

Comment: I'm intrigued by why you need a specific build. Could you elaborate on it a bit? Just for curiosity's sake. I've used different builds and vendors of Java 8 in a single project without issues, so I might need to keep your reasons in mind.

Comment: I want to use it set JAVA_HOME in the container. When the Build number change the path changes and script fails.

Comment: You know you can write code to detect the path that actually exists and make a constant symlink to it? Most distros have Java packaging do that for you so you don't need to know the real path at all